# save binary to an image file in node js

Tags: node.js, buffer, fs

I'm receiving response.data in a binary
I can save a file test.jpg when open in notepad it's a binary text like this:

> ���� JFIF  H H  ��*Exif  MM *                  b       j(       1       r2       ��i       �   �
> ��  '
> ��  'Adobe Photoshop CS4 Windows 2009:01:31 22:25:45    �    ��  �      @�      >                          &(             .      �       H      H   ���� JFIF   H H  �� Adobe_CM �� !1AQa"q�2���B#$R�b34r��C%�S���cs5���&D�TdE£t6�U�e���u��F'���������������Vfv��������7GWgw�������� 5 !1AQaq"2����B#�R��3$b�r��CScs4�%���&5��D�T�dEU6te����u��F���������A�̰Y���u��7��l8��Z��~e����eXj�Γ���e�fSˁ�'E���q��X%h��� �.���2v�8#������llx;����h $���

```
var img = response.data;
var path = "D:/Picture";
var filename = "test.jpg";
var buf = Buffer.from(img, 'binary');

fs.writeFileSync(path + "/" + filename, buf, function(error) {
 if (error) {
  console.error("write error:  " + error.message);
  } else {
  console.log("Successful Write to " + path);
 }
});
```

cannot open as an image
What's am I wrong?

Comment: Why you need from binary, Cany you just use simple base64 image encoding?

Comment: actually, response.data from line api https://api-data.line.me/v2/bot/message/{messageId}/content in a binary how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this,

```
fs.writeFile("test.jpg", response.data, 'binary', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('File saved.')
});
```